# Speed Up Image Sharpening and Related Image Optimizations in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, imaging

My goal is to allow the user to improve image quality by providing the options to improve the ***sharpness,Contrast etc*** of a Bitmap

I have followed the approach mentioned in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2008/Image-Processing-for-Dummies-with-C-and-GDI-Part This works quite well for small resolution images.But for large resolution images taken using a DSLR (eg:6000X400 Pixels) this approach is really slow.I understand this is the limitation of GDI+ and Bitmap in General,so i looked for some Frameworks to process large resolution images.
***Aforge*** seemed like a good choice,but it also takes considerable amount of time to process large resolution images.

eg:

```
GaussianSharpen filter = new GaussianSharpen(4, 11);
filter.ApplyInPlace(bm_dest);
```

Can someone please advise me a Fast Library or Tool (be it non .NET command line tools,i can call it using CMD and update the Picturebox Image) to solve this issue.

Comment: "Can someone please advise me a Fast Library or Tool" - with 1.5k Rep you should know that this is OT. But: Maybe it's worth researching in the direction of "[Computation on the **G**PU](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/basic_linear_transform/basic_linear_transform.html)" ?

Answer (score 1):

Gdiplus has its own [Sharpen class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms534503(v=vs.85).aspx)

This should be significantly faster than manipulating bits manually.

Requires GDI plus version 1.1, for Windows Vista and above. Example:

```
#define GDIPVER 0x0110

void test_sharpen(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);

    Image img(L"test.jpg");
    graphics.DrawImage(&img, 0.0f, 0.0f, (REAL)img.GetWidth(), (REAL)img.GetHeight());

    SharpenParams sharpen_param;
    sharpen_param.amount = 50;
    sharpen_param.radius = 100;

    Sharpen sharpen;
    sharpen.SetParameters(&sharpen_param);

    RectF rect(0.0f, 0.0f, (REAL)img.GetWidth(), (REAL)img.GetHeight());
    Matrix matrix_offset(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 400.0, 0.0f);
    graphics.DrawImage(&img, &rect, &matrix_offset, &sharpen, NULL, UnitPixel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... dont know why this answer was downvoted.I have upvoted it.